# Who has the most impressive track record of gaining rep quickly on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

The rep game at stackoverflow is intriguing and fun.

Which SO user acumulated rep faster than any other user. Let's take several "quickly" windows of say:

- 1 hour
- 1 day
- 1 week
- 1 month
- 1 year

What user earned reputation fastest in the given period and what can the gain be attributed to (eg: a great question, a great answer, lots of one or the other, etc...)?

You needn't answer the whole question. Perhaps your answer only addresses one of the period windows or perhaps it addresses a particular tactic.

Disclaimer: I am halfway through a bottle of Shiraz as I ask this, so don't take your answers too seriously.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [tags-stats-page without any tags selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=&sort=stats). It displays the number of votes.

> ### Top answerers
>
> #### Last 30 Days
>
> 1536 313 [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)
>   _962 358 [Jonathan Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680/jonathan-sampson)
>   _902 272 [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli)
>   _874 350 [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka)

The first number represents the number of upvotes - downvotes and the second the number of answers.

Comment: Hey, neat! I didn't know you could list those stats with no tags selected.

Comment: I think it is more useful to look at the 0 to x numbers.  Looking at your figures is useless since that encompasses more than a year of answeres and questions that can be upvoted.

Comment: I don't think the link works anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) certainly wins on the year scale, so he'd be a good bet at any scale. [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) is catching up at a frightening rate, though. Taken more granularly: anyone who has won a 550 bounty. I don't think I have. I'm pretty sure I've gone well into the 500+ in a day, but only with bounty. My best without bounty is just under 400, but I'm pretty sure this has been beaten by Jon and/or Alex.

Comment: 400? Are you sure there's not an extra 0 in there? Impressive, I congratulate you, sir!

Comment: I've slowed down though; these days I'm more-or-less averaging only 215.

Comment: That is not slowing down, trust me, especially with 100k+ next to your name.

Comment: you're right about Martelli. That guy's track record is alarming!

Comment: I thought you'd done about 420 in a day before now... I think my best is about 470.

Comment: @Jon - quite possibly; I wonder if the data-dump would tell me, but to be honest I can't be bothered to check ;-p

Comment: 350 answered and ~6000 rep, I'm doing something wrong (apart from the obvious idiot factor)

Comment: @Chris - if you do the math, as a per-answer rate that is *about* the same as me/Jon/Alex.

Comment: @Marc: I have a program which will fetch one day's data at a time ever 100ms or so (to avoid spamming the server). It then logs the totals. That ignores your own downvotes, mind you. I may run it on me, you and Alex to have a little look...

Comment: I look at some rates when first setting up stackql, and Alex had a higher "velocity" than Marc, but still lower than Jon.  It looks like he may still be accelerating, though.

Answer (score 2):

In 1 year, the answer is obviously Jon Skeet.
(I'm guessing in the other windows also)

It can be attributed to him knowing a lot of stuff

Comment: Just checked your profile. LOL at the downvote and close remark!

Answer (score 2):

Well, as mentioned elsewhere I'm kind of cheating here, since I got one of the lucrative 550 bounties ;-)

But my records for reputation:

- 1 minute: 550 ;-)
- 1 hour: 580
- 1 day: 620

I'm not going to put the rest down, since it there are bunches of people average in the thousands of rep per week. Jon Skeet for example has a lifetime average of about 300 per day.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java/245068#245068) has to be the easiest way to get 1700 rep - if it was trickled over time. Make a populist soundbite statement, +N<sup>2</sup> rep

Comment: @grenade Yes that answer my mistake

Comment: that was a spectacularly well placed, 11 word, answer.

Comment: Sometimes you just get lucky. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This legendary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) from bobince earned him over 900 Rep, probably in just a few days. Maybe it isn't the fastest *Rep growth* (due to the Rep cap), but I think it's certainly the fastest accumulation of upvotes.

Comment: shame about the community wiki, that would have been epic. It's funny, if it had been possible to vote on revision comments (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1732454/list, "i done made another mistake-up"), bobince would have got another 1k rep on that answer.